# Is there a specific reason Apple doesn't allow a .xib to be created when making a subclass of UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview

Just wondering why Apple would allow the creation of .xib file when making a UIViewController, but not allow it when subclassing a UIView.

Comment: Because `UIViewController` contains the logic to load a NIB file and `UIView` does not.

Comment: Views or controls are supposed to be really fast to initialise. If you need a xib to implement it - you are probably doing something wrong. View controllers on the other hand provide special interface to make the views loading manageable.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a `.xib` to instantiate a `UIView`. Just create an empty `.xib`, drag a `UIView` out, change it's class, and instantiate it with `UINib`

e.g.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
NSArray *views = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
MyCustomView *myView = [views firstObject];
```

Comment: I'm aware that you can, just unsure of why Apple doesn't make it easier than it is.

Comment: @dkind How would you go about making it any easier?

Comment: @dkind You asked point-blank why apple _won't_ allow you to do it. Now you're saying you're aware that you can? I would rephrase your question. This seems like a pretty easy approach to me.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I think the OP is talking about creating the .xib in Xcode, not instantiating at runtime.

Comment: @Caleb it would appear so, given the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear, but I'm guessing that you're talking about creating the files in Xcode, not instantiating a view or view controller at runtime. Xcode disables the "create .xib" checkbox when you create a file containing a UIView subclass and enables it when you create a UIViewController subclass. The reason is simply that there's usually a correspondence between view controllers and .xib files -- if you're using .xib files, you *typically* create a .xib for each type of view controller in your project.

You don't *typically* create a .xib for each view. On the contrary, it's unusual to instantiate a view from a .xib separately from a view controller. The only time I can think of when it makes sense is when you have something like a complex table cell that you'll instantiate over and over in the same view controller. And these days, most people doing that kind of thing are probably using storyboards anyway.